# PHP - How to make a search engine to search from a date to another date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a php file to search in my database table "attendance". 
I want to get the values from a date to another date.

For e.g. |Date1| |Date2|
|Values displayed from date1 to date2|

My table contains `emp_id`, `Date`, `Day`, `Time_In`, `Time_Out`, `Worked`, `Overtime`, `Less_Hours`, `Transport_In`, `Transport_Out`.

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance
**EDIT 1:**

```
<?php
    require_once 'Connection.simple.php';
    $conn = dbConnect();
    $OK = true;
    if (isset($_GET['employee_id'])) {
        $data = "%".$_GET['employee_id']."%";
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM employee WHERE employee_id like ?';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $results = $stmt->execute(array($data));
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        $error = $stmt->errorInfo();
    }
    if(empty($rows)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan='4'>There were not records</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    else {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['employee_id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['telephone']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
?>
```

I have tried this simple code to search in my database table but i don't know how to go further.
I am just a begginer
Rgds
Akshat

**EDIT 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('.btnSearch').click(function(){
                makeAjaxRequest();
            });

            $('form').submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                makeAjaxRequest();
                return false;
            });

            function makeAjaxRequest() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'php/search.php',
                    type: 'get',
                    DateFrom: {DateFrom: $('input#DateFrom').val()},
                    DateTo: {DateTo: $('input#DateTo').val()},
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('table#resultTable tbody').html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
```

This is the code that i am using on the index.html page

Rgds
Akshat

Comment: You can use an SQL query for that...

Comment: Use an SQL query with `BETWEEN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a [WHERE-Clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm) with [BETWEEN](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-between-clause.htm) like this:

```
//Option with fixdate (Default if no Dateinformation in the url)
$dateFrom = "2014-12-15";
$dateTo = "2015-01-15";

//Or set with GET parameter (Parameter from your URL like employee_id)
//URL Example myPHPPage.php?employee_id=MA-1299&DateFrom=2014-12-15&DateTo2015-01-15

if (isset($_GET['DateFrom']) && isset($_GET['DateFrom'])) {    
    $dateFrom = $_GET['DateFrom'];
    $dateTo = $_GET['DateTo'];
}

$sql = "SELECT *
          FROM `employee`
         WHERE (Date BETWEEN '" . $dateFrom . "' AND '" . $dateTo . "' ) 
           AND `employee_id` like " . $data
```

Comment: how can i use . $data . instead of '2014-12-15'

Comment: $data is your employee_id from $data = "%".$_GET['employee_id']."%";

Comment: I changed data to be $data = "%".$_GET['minimum_date']."%" and created one $data1 = "%".$_GET['maximum_date']."%"

Comment: you dont need "%" for date.. "%" is a wildcard. i have extended my answer

Comment: Can you just tell me what should i put here **if (isset($_GET['DateFrom'])) {**

Comment: jap. i have updated my answer. isset checks if there a parameter in your url

Comment: It is showing an error 247544 if i keep the } before **$sql = "SELECT *
          FROM `employee`
         WHERE (Date BETWEEN '" . $dateFrom . "' AND '" . $dateTo . "' )** and i removed the **AND `employee_id` like " . $data** because i don't need it anymore

Comment: [Files Link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dpeyxmh6ewtd8sp/AAD7oM3hktq6ck4Bw4hpj3YSa?dl=0).

Answer (score 1):

The query would be along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE `date` >='minimum date'  AND `date` <='maximum date'
```

If your dates are as a timestamp it would be easy.

You can use this: http://www.epochconverter.com/

Otherwise you can still do it easily by just using the date format ur dB is using.